# Core Plot - iOS Touched Event is difficult to select point on graph

Tags: ios, select, core-plot, point, scatter-plot

Using this function

```
- (void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

I can add an annotation to a selected point, although it is diffucult to select one point on the graph with your finger on an iPad or iPhone. Is there anyway to enable this function to be more forgiving for a finger pointing device instead of a mouse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection` property on the scatter plot. This defines the distance from the center of a plot point, given in pixels, where a touch will still register.

Comment: Yes, thats perfect. Thank you.Any idea of off the top of your head what a good point range for iPhone would be? [my gist for ipad](https://gist.github.com/2032690) looks like 10.0f is decent.

Comment: 10.0 sounds reasonable to me.